# Heroku rails queuing mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, mongoid

I need to proccess a `csv` file with 10,000 records in it. It takes about 4 seconds per 100 records, and I'm cool with it.
I want to be able to split the 10,000 record to 100 jobs, that will be executed when server is not busy(no order needed).

I'm working with heroku, and if I can, I'll be happy to distribute the handling to a few nodes.

What's best practice here? How to handle the mongo connection? How to split the job, and create this tasks that will run in future?

Don't need a full solution just some guidance please.

Comment: I'd probably use something like [Sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/). It requires redis, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have the same suggestion as Sergio. Try the [**Sidekiq**](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) background worker gem. There's the [kiqstand](https://github.com/mongoid/kiqstand) middleware that makes it work with Mongoid.

Rough possible sketch:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'kiqstand'
gem 'sidekiq'


# Procfile
web: ...
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -e $RACK_ENV -C config/sidekiq.yml


# config/sidekiq.yml
#
# Configuration file for Sidekiq.
# Options here can still be overridden by cmd line args.
---
:verbose: false
:namespace: sidekiq
:concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - [often, 7]
  - [default, 5]
  - [seldom, 3]


# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  # Require kiqstand middleware
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Kiqstand::Middleware
  end
end

# app/workers/import_worker.rb
# The actual Sidekiq worker that performs the input
class ImportWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(my_var)
    # processing the csv
  end
end
```

Sidekiq and Kiqstand should handle the Mongoid Mongodb connections. For splitting the tasks you could create a second worker that feeds the first one. As the arguments sent to `ImportWorker.perform_async(my_var)` will be serialized and stored in Redis they should be small, just a row reference or so in your case.

Hope that gives a few pointers.

Answer (score 0):

also have a look at the smarter_csv gem - which is designed to read CSV files in batches, so you can hand them off to a resque or sidekiq worker..

https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv